# Chrome Only: Fixed Div w/Google Map scrolls when other div scrolls

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, css-position

I'm having an issue with two of my divs.  One of them is fixed (.post), the other is relative(.imageStyle):

```
.post{
position:fixed;right:0px;top:0px;bottom:0px;width:48%;background:#fff;
color:black;box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px #1f1f1f;text-shadow:none;
overflow:auto;height:100%;z-index:99999
}

.imageStyle{width:45%;position:relative;background:#1f1f1f;
margin:0px;padding:0px;height:100%;z-index:5}
```

Inside of .post is an implementation of Google Maps V3.  In IE & Firefox, the Map displays as expected; when i scroll down in .imageStyle div, .post stays fixed where its supposed to be.  However, in Chrome, when I scroll in down inside of .imageStyle, the map stays where its supposed to be, but the rest of the content of .post scrolls with .imageStyle (or behaves as if it was relative).

This is especially weird because on every other page I have with these divs, the content inside of .post behaves properly on ALL browsers.  Furthermore, this problem only persists in Chrome.

The Google Maps is an implementation of Google Maps V3 API being served from my IDX vendor.  The CSS for their implementation looks like this:

```
/*** Map Search (Template #1) ***/
#IDX-propTypeTextLinks {display:none;}
#IDX-searchNavWrapper {margin:5px auto; text-align:left;position:relative;}
#IDX-mapPropertyTypes {float:left; width:192px;}
#IDX-mapPropertyTypes select {border:1px #AAA solid; float:left; width:182px;}

/* This link allows a user to save a map search directly */
#IDX-saveMapSearch {float:left;}
#IDX-googleMap {width:100%; height:600px; clear:both; position:relative;  overflow:hidden; border:1px #000  solid; margin:10px 0;}

/* This holds the informational text regarding the number of properties found in a     given search */
#IDX-mapInfo {width:400px; height:14px; margin:5px 0 5px 0; float:left; left:5px; font-size:11px; text-align:left;}

/* The controls float near the google map and add additional features to the core  Google Controls */
#IDX-mapControls {padding:0px; margin:0px;/*width:97px;*/ height:100%;  position:relative; top:0; left:0;/* background:url(/images/layout/mapSearch/20- controlBg.jpg) top left repeat-y; border-right:1px #AAA  solid;*/visibility:hidden;display:none;height:0px;width:0px;}
#IDX-mapContainer {color:#000; background:#E5E3DF  url(http://www.idxco.com/images/layout/gload.gif) top center no- repeat;width:100%;height:602px;}
#IDX-mapContainer a:link, #IDX-mapContainer a:hover, #IDX-mapContainer a:active, #IDX-mapContainer a:visited {color:#000;}

/* The mapWithContainer should normally be #IDX-googleMap width minus #IDX-mapControls width minus border width. In this case, 560 - 96 - 3 = 472px */
.IDX-mapWithContainer {width:464px; height:360px; position:relative; top:0; left:0px;}
.IDX-mapWithoutContainer {width:100%; height:100%;}
#IDX-mapOverlay {width:150px; height:50px; position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px; z-index:500; display:none; background:url(/images/layout/mapSearch/overlay.gif);}


/* Mode switching allows the map to be drawn with different tilesets */
.mapTypeButton {cursor:pointer; margin:0; padding:0; border:0;}
#IDX-modeRow {width:96px; height:131px; position:relative; clear:both; background:url(/images/layout/mapSearch/20-modeBg.jpg);}
#IDX-mapTypeMap {width:76px; height:20px; position:absolute; top:34px; left:10px; background:url(/images/layout/mapSearch/20-modeMap.jpg);}
#IDX-mapTypeSat {width:76px; height:20px; position:absolute; top:56px; left:10px; background:url(/images/layout/mapSearch/20-modeSat.jpg);}
#IDX-mapTypeHyb {width:76px; height:20px; position:absolute; top:78px; left:10px; background:url(/images/layout/mapSearch/20-modeHyb.jpg);}
#IDX-mapTypeTer {width:76px; height:20px; position:absolute; top:100px; left:10px; background:url(/images/layout/mapSearch/20-modeTer.jpg);}

/* The following CSS controls the general search controls */
#IDX-searchForm {margin:0; padding:0;}
#IDX-searchBoxWrapper {width:555px; height:60px; clear:both; margin:0; padding-bottom:20px;}
#IDX-searchBox {width:500px; height:55px; margin:0 auto; float:left; position:relative; left:97px;}

/* This container should be as large as the #IDX-googleMap declaration (minus borders, of course) */
#IDX-mapBasicBox {width:100%;height:600px}
#IDX-mapBasicBox input, #IDX-mapBasicBox select {border:1px #AAA solid;}
#lowPrice, #highPrice, #sqFt, #daysOnMarket, #acres {width:100px;}

/* These elements will be display and need CSS */
#IDX-mapMinPrice {float:left; width:110px; height:40px; margin-top:4px;}
#IDX-mapMaxPrice {float:left; width:110px; height:40px; margin-top:4px;}

#IDX-mapSearchAcres {display:none; float:left; width:110px; height:40px; margin-top:4px;}

#IDX-mapSearchBedRooms {float:left; width:110px; height:40px; margin-top:4px;}
#IDX-mapSearchBathRooms {float:left; width:110px; height:40px; margin-top:4px;}
#IDX-mapSearchBedRooms select {width:100px;}
#IDX-mapSearchBathRooms select {width:100px;}
#IDX-mapSearchHelpText {clear:both; text-align:center; font-size:8pt;    filter:alpha(opacity=50); -moz-opacity:.50; opacity:.50;visibility:hidden;}
```

I've tried tweaking with the position of both the aforementioned divs and the Map CSS and cant seem to get it to work in Chrome.At the moment I am assuming that the problem is somehow related to either the Google Maps API itself, or the CSS for it. Any and all help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Also, I want to mention that the issue does not appear untill the google map has finished loading.  In other words, if you are on a slow connection, or if you block the map function, you can see that all the elements behave correctly UNTILL the map is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

So after continued searching, I found a partial solution that dates back almost three years.  Apparently the issue is with webkit:

```
*{-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased !important;
-webkit-transform: none !important;}
```

This fixes the issue I had with the fixed div, but now I cant "move" through the map (For example: If I'm looking at Miami, FL and I try to click and drag the map, it moves but does not ever load the new map area).

Funny thing is this is an issue that Google was aware of three years ago but still hasn't fixed (The solution above came directly from  Google's forums: Issue 1411 Gmaps-api-issues).